# Xamarin with Azure MobileServiceUser

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm having some trouble with learning Xamarin, I realize this is a high level question, I apologize.

I have successfully been able to authenticate with FB as my auth provider, and have been able to use loginasync to authenticate with my app backend, however how do I continue to use that user that has been logged in after you've moved to a different activity?  After I've brought up a new activity, when I call my app service, I get the unauthorized error.

Just finding a lack of documentation/samples on how a project should be set up while using a MobileServiceUser across the whole app.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the "Sport" sample app from Xamarin [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Sport/tree/50b5896e17b86d88df53175fea5f4b1fa99b1164) which uses `MobileServiceUser`.

Even tho it is a forms app (and you are looking for an Android sample) you can see how it manages to use the [Settings](https://github.com/xamarin/Sport/blob/50b5896e17b86d88df53175fea5f4b1fa99b1164/Sport.Shared/Settings.cs) singleton class to keep a reference to the `MobileServiceUser` `user` property. [This](https://github.com/xamarin/Sport/blob/50b5896e17b86d88df53175fea5f4b1fa99b1164/Sport.Shared/ViewModels/AuthenticationViewModel.cs#L94) is where the app sets that property like so:

```
AuthenticationStatus = "Loading...";
MobileServiceUser user = await _authenticator.DisplayWebView();

var identity = await AzureService.Instance.Client.InvokeApiAsync("getUserIdentity", null, HttpMethod.Get, null);

App.AuthToken = identity.Value<string>("accessToken");
Utility.SetSecured("AuthToken", App.AuthToken, "xamarin.sport", "authentication");

Settings.Instance.User = user;
await Settings.Instance.Save();
```

There are some more samples in the xamarin docs [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/azure/#Samples)

This [Todo app](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/a8ea3c90dec5cff968ffa0c0cfcf84885234b172/Azure/GettingStarted) also has a similar pattern with its [TodoService](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/blob/a8ea3c90dec5cff968ffa0c0cfcf84885234b172/Azure/GetStartedWithUsers/iOS/XamarinTodoQuickStart/TodoService.cs) singleton

Comment: Thanks, I had found samples but haven't gone through that one yet, appreciate your response and I'll take a look at it.  I admit, especially being new, I tried to stay away from Xamarin.Forms as I didn't want to get confused.  Good to know.

Thanks again for your response and sample code!